# Facebook Page a Mandatory Step for Entry Submission

Tags: facebook-graph-api, interface-builder

I want to make my facebook page like mandatory for submission same as below article but I am not getting where

"Promotion Builder under Application > Integration > Facebook Like Box" is located.

http://support.strutta.com/kb/facebook-integration/how-to-make-liking-my-facebook-page-a-mandatory-step-for-entry-submission

I will find it in Facebook apps settings or page where apps are shown?

Any solution?

- Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Seamless way to check if user likes page](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/5329818/seamless-way-to-check-if-user-likes-page)

Answer (score 0):

The setting you are referring to is part of Strutta's web app, **not** Facebook. Assuming you have an Strutta PRO account, you must login to your account to activate the setting:

http://www.strutta.com/auth/login?destination=account